# Why unbalanced multi columns work with standalone but not work with article?

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol, enumitem, standalone, article

I want to have unbalanced multi columns for 5 multiple choice options. It means that the last option must not be aligned with the third option.

By default `multicols` makes balanced column in which the last option and the third option have the same alignment line. But  `multicols*` should not make them get aligned. Unfortunately `multicols*` only works with `standalone` but not with `article`.

The following MWE shows what I meant.

### With `standalone`

[image]

### With `article`

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{article}% try it with standalone
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
\item \SI{1}{\square\meter} 
\item \SI{2}{\square\meter} 
\item \SI{3}{\square\meter} 
\item \SI{4}{\square\meter} 
\item \SI{5}{\square\meter} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}


\lipsum[2]
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
\item \SI{1}{\square\meter} 
\item \SI{2}{\square\meter} 
\item \SI{3}{\square\meter} 
\item \SI{4}{\square\meter} 
\item \SI{5}{\square\meter} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols*}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Manual says, : `if you
use multicols* instead of the
usual environment the columns
on the last page are not balanced.
Of course, this environment only
works on top-level, e.g., inside a
box one has to balance to deter-
mine a column height in absence
of a fixed value.` so you have to put it in a box/last page. Put it in , say, a `minipage` and see.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Thanks. Do you want to get a green checkmark?

Comment: Sure :-). In some time though. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what manual says:

[image]

Therefore for `multicol*` to work one needs to box it. We can either put a `\parbox` or `minipage` surrounding the environment.

```
 %\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}% try it with standalone
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
\item \SI{1}{\square\meter}
\item \SI{2}{\square\meter}
\item \SI{3}{\square\meter}
\item \SI{4}{\square\meter}
\item \SI{5}{\square\meter}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `standalone` is already a box kind of thing with only one page.